# Filemaker WebDirect

Tags: filemaker

I am new to filemaker and have been using it since 2 weeks. Is there any way by which we can create a url for a specific record located in a particular layout so that when we fire up that url only that record appears on web. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @AndreasT gave you the answer, but I think the issue is in the problem you are trying to solve. There is a good reason why this functionality is not there. May be if you describe the problem you are trying to solve we can suggest alternative, more secure solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. This feature was removed in later versions for security reasons. You can however pass a script name and parameter which would enable you to script the process and go to the layout/record you want.

```
http://<host>/fmi/webd/<database name>[?script=<script name>[&param=<script parameter>][&<$variable name>=<value>]]
```

More on this in the [WebDirect](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/fmwd/) guide.

Edit:

```
The URL:
http://<host>/fmi/webd/Database?script=WD_GoToReCord&param=xxxx
```

Where xxxx is the record ID of the relevant record.

```
The FileMaker script:
Name: WD_GoToReCord

# Performs a record search and goes to layout for display
# Requires a field in the database that is unique per record.
# The example uses a calculation field named RecordID with the calculation Get(RecordID)

Set Variable [ $recordID ; Value: Get(ScriptParameter) ] 
If [ IsEmpty ( $recordID ) ] 
    Exit Script [ Text Result:    ] 
End If
Set Error Capture [ On ]
Go to Layout [ “Record Search” ; Animation: None ]
Enter Find Mode [ Pause: Off ] 
Set Field [ Database::RecordID ; $recordID ] 
Perform Find [] 
If [ Get(FoundCount) = 1 ] 
    Go to Layout [ “Switchboard” ; Animation: None ]
Else
    # show some error or ignore
End If
```

Comment: Hi @AndreasT! Thanks for your answer. I encountered this line of code while searching for the answer, However I don't know what to write in that script. Also, does that script have to written in php? Can you specify how to do it. 
The name of my database is Database
My layout name from which I want to fetch records is switchboard
Thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example URL and a sample script. I have not tested this as such and there may be some details to adjust, but this should get you going.

Comment: Hi There! Thank you very much for your help. 
I did exactly what you have specified and my only problem is it is navigating to the first record always, despite specifying different param values in the url. 

one problem in my script is, it is only accepting one parameter value for Set Field, how can I specify like you have done?
Also, If you could clear out what is  "Record Search" doing here.

Comment: 'Set Field' accepts 2 parameters. First is the field name to set, the second is the value, in this case the variable $recordID. The script is performing a search for the value in $recordID, provided by the script parameter in the URL. If your 'Set Field' is wrong, it will fail. You can try the script on a FileMaker Pro by calling it from another script and specifying various script parameters. The 'Record Search' layout I suggested is just a staging layout to perform the search on. You may use the same layout as you want to display the result on if you prefer as long as it is the same table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, it is working perfectly!